# html table with horizontal scroll and fixed cell width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Can anyone help me with a html table with horizontal scroll and fixed cell width?

I can make a table with horizontal scroll, see below, but I am not able to adjust the cell widths in this table. Any suggestion? Thanks.

BTW I am using bootstrap 4 if that helps.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make one column fixed with horizontal scroll using Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846478/make-one-column-fixed-with-horizontal-scroll-using-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `table-layout:fixed;` for your table.

```css
.MainDiv {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.MainDiv table td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="MainDiv">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
      <td>124567890</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm maybe but how do I adjust the width of each column? To e.g. 25% for some and 10% for others.

Comment: for `td` if you start giving it as `%` then whole value is considered as `100%` so making it `25%` will shorten the width.

Comment: for different `td` width you have to provide different selector class and give your custom width sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the property width's value of the table to "max-content" like this:

```html
 <style>
        table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 0;
          width: max-content;
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        th, td {
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
          width: 100px;
        }


    </style>

    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td >Test</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

"max-content" value is not supported by Internet Explorer: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/width

Another solution which works in all web browsers, is to add the property "table-layout: fixed" to the table's style and specify the width you want of your cells, like this:

```html
 <style>
        table {
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 0;
          width: 100%;
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          table-layout: fixed;
        }

        th, td {
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
          width: 100px;
        }


    </style>

    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td >Test</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
            <td>124567890</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

[Refer to this link for more informations about "table-layout" and the supported browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)